# What is a difference between abstract and virtual?

Tags: c#

both abstract and virtual are going to be override in child class than whats a difference.

is it Virtual method have body and abstract is just a signature ????

Comment: As an aside, partial methods, in contrast to abstract methods, allow you to create methods without implementations that do not need to be overridden.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> is it Virtual method have body and abstract is just a signature ????

Exactly. The point is that virtual methods *can* be overridden in derived classes, while abstract methods **must** be overridden. Likewise, a class that has at least one abstract method must itself be abstract, i.e. it cannot be instantiated directly since its implementation is (partially) missing.

Finally, every abstract method is *also* virtual by implication. `virtual` basically just means that the method is dispatched at runtime to the correct class, and so it can be overridden to implement runtime polymorphism.

Comment: Since abstract methods MUST be overwritten, they are in fact a contract like interfaces and code would compile unless you implement them correctly, so it is a way to get the users of your code to implement code they must implement, especially if they are lazy, correct?

Comment: @Xaisoft Correct, but virtual (non-abstract) methods also form a contract since a contract is from the perspective of using classes (= clients). All that’s important is that a client can use the functions of a class that it advertises.

Comment: I agree, but what I meant was that if you declare a method virtual, a client does not have to implement it even though they should. Also a virtual method can have default behavior.  A client has to implement an abstract method and it can't have default behavior.  It seems the only reason you would go the abstract route vs the virtual route was if you really really wanted to enforce a method be implemented and the onus be put on the client.

Comment: @Xaisoft Ah yes. That’s it precisely.

Answer (score 20):

Abstract means you MUST override it. Virtual means you CAN override it. More or less.

Comment: Adding to that: With abstract methods in your class your whole class will be abstract which means you cannot create instances of this class, only of derived non-abstract subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with both answers here, so I won't repeat them. But here's a link that might help.

[10.6.3 Virtual, sealed, override, and abstract accessors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664453(VS.71).aspx)